# WordPress Plugin Update Process

Tags: plugin-development, updates

I am developing a wordpress plugin which involves creating a table in the wp database.

I have included an uninstall.php file to remove the table from the wp database when the user decides to delete the plugin from wp admin dashboard.

The thing is that,i want to know whether the uninstall.php file is executed during the update process if i provide an update through the wp plugin repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not. The uninstall.php file will only be run if a user deactivates the plugin and clicks the delete action.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/uninstall-methods/